# I want to Remove a print function if Someone choose another option in python

Tags: python

I have three print function in python basically these a option 1 2 3 if someone choose 1 after that when it again come to these steps beacause it is infinite loop i want to remove option 3 from there basically i want to remove  print function.
Please help me .
Thanks in Advance .
Is it ok if i use a if else here !!!!!!

this is portion where i want to do that

In this i want third print removed after if Someone chose choice 1

```
self.blackjack = False
print(f" Press 1 For Hit a New Card ")
print(" Press 2 For Stand ")
print(" Press 3 for Double ")
choice = int(input(" Enter Your Choice: "))
if choice == 1:

    running = self.hitTheCard()
elif choice == 2:
    self.stand()
    running = False
elif choice == 3:
    self.betAmount *= 2
    running = self.hitTheCard()
    self.player.displayCardInHand()
    if running:
        self.stand()
        running = False
else:
    print(" Invalid choice given try again.")
```

Feel free give me advices please

Comment: Seeing some of the other supporting code (such as the loop this is in, or if its a function, the code calling the function) could be helpful.  
   Presumably you have a list or other collection tracking the cards in the player's hand.  If the player has hit already chosen to hit, then they must have > 2 cards in hand, so you can use their hand size as a check for whether or not the 3rd option should be displayed.  And you need to also check the hand size before processing the `elif choice==3` branch, otherwise they could enter 3 even if it isn't displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your options in a dictionary; then you can loop over the dictionary to display the available options, and delete them from the dictionary when you want them to no longer be available.

```
options = {
    '1': ("Hit a New Card", self.hitTheCard),
    '2': ("Stand", self.stand),
    '3': ("Double", self.double),
}

while True:
    for opt, (desc, _func) in options.items():
        print(f"Press {opt} for {desc}")
    choice = input("Enter your choice: ")
    if choice not in options:
        print("Invalid choice, try again.")
        continue
    _desc, func = options[choice]
    del options[choice]
    func()
```

Comment: The line `print(f"Press {opt} for {desc}")` should be indented.  Also note he doesn't want to delete the selected option.  It's only that option 3 should not be available if option 1 has been selected at once while the current hand of blackjack is still being played.  Option 3 should be available again on the next hand.

Comment: yes sir you r right i want that